# Linked List Pointers | what's that mean: next is reference and can be viewed as a link or pointer?

Tags: javascript, pointers, linked-list, javascript-objects

My question is about **Linked List and Pointers**
I know linkedlist and how it's work, but my problem is that:

I have this example odd-even linked list :

```
// This is class node for create nodes
class Node {
    constructor(val, next) {
        this.val = val === undefined ? 0 : val;
        this.next = next === undefined ? null : next;
    }
}

// this is our function to return odd nodes followed bt even nodes 
// * return the index of node not the value so if node index is 1 and value is 2 
// thats mean odd node not even cuz we don't care about value
// consider that index start from 1 not from 0

const oddEvenLinkedList = function (head) {
    if (!head) return head;
    var odd = head
    var even = head.next 
    var evenHead = even 
    while (odd.next) {
        odd.next = even.next 
        odd = odd.next 
        even.next = odd.next 
        even = even.next 
    }
    odd.next = evenHead
    return head;  
};
// create our linked list
// Node takes two params Node(value, next_node)
const head = new Node(1, 
             new Node(2, 
             new Node(3, 
             new Node(4, 
             new Node(5, 
             new Node(6, 
             new Node(7)))))))

console.log(oddEvenLinkedList(head));
```

The result will be :

```
head = [1,3,5,2,4,6,7] // odd numbers followed by even nubmers
```

so my question is :
what's happened here when we added :

```
    var odd = head
    var even = head.next 
    var evenHead = even
```

I know the `odd` var now will be : `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`
and at the same time `even` will be : `[2,3,4,5,6,7]`

the problem is : `odd` and `even` after loop will be equals to:

```
   odd = [7] 
   even = null
```

and at the last line when we add : `odd.next = evenHead`
that's mean `odd` will be equal to `odd=[7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`
but when I return `odd` will be something like this: `odd=[1,3,5,2,4,6,7]`

and at the same time when I return `head` will be equal to `odd` the same result :
`head=[1,3,5,2,4,6,7]`

why `odd` var effects on `head` and `even` var effect on `evenHead` ?

I hope you understand what I mean:

**simple summary if you don't understand the above explanation**

```
let head = [1,2,3,4,5] // linked list 1->2->3...etc
let x = main
let z = main

//for example when change x or z :
x.next = null
//or 
z.next = null // or whatever value

// any changes we do in z or x will affect the head, why?
```

```js
class Node {
    constructor(val, next) {
        this.val = val === undefined ? 0 : val;
        this.next = next === undefined ? null : next;
    }
}

var oddEvenLinkedList = function (head) {
    if (!head) return head;
    var odd = head 
    var even = head.next 
    var evenHead = even 
    while (odd.next) {
        odd.next = even.next 
        odd = odd.next 
        even.next = odd.next 
        even = even.next 
    }
    odd.next = evenHead
    return head;  
};
const head = new Node(1, new Node(2, new Node(3, new Node(4, new Node(5, new Node(6, new Node(7)))))))

console.log(oddEvenLinkedList(head));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `odd.next = evenHead` that means `odd` will be equal to `odd=[7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` but when I return `odd` it is something like this: `odd=[1,3,5,2,4,6,7]`

The reason is that the loop has rewired the list. Before the loop executes, the list, starting from `head`, is:

```
 odd
head         
  ↓
  1→2→3→4→5→6→7
    ↑
 evenHead
   even
```

But the loop redirects all those "arrows", so that *after* the loop, the links are as follows:

```
head         odd
  ↓           ↓
  1→→→3→→→5→→→7
    2→→→4→→→6
    ↑       ↑
 evenHead  even
```

And when the last assignment has been executed, we get the final result:

```
head         odd
  ↓           ↓
  1→→→3→→→5→→→7→→→2→→→4→→→6
                  ↑       ↑
               evenHead  even
```

So if then you would look at `odd`, you will find the following list sequence: [7, 2, 4, 6]. If the purpose would have been to *first* get all odd values and *then* all even values, then the statements after the loop should change from this:

```
odd.next = evenHead
return head;
```

to this:

```
even.next = head
return evenHead;
```

They would be executed when the state is as follows (I repeat):

```
head         odd
  ↓           ↓
  1→→→3→→→5→→→7
    2→→→4→→→6
    ↑       ↑
 evenHead  even
```

But with these final statements we get this:

```
              head         odd
                ↓           ↓
    2→→→4→→→6→→→1→→→3→→→5→→→7
    ↑       ↑
 evenHead  even
```

...and then `evenHead` would be returned, so the sequence would then be [2, 4, 6, 1, 3, 5, 7].

Comment: appreciate ur answer & ur time. 
But I'm still a bit confusing, why when we assigned `odd.next = evenHead` the result will be : `[1,3,5,7,...etc]` 
and we know `odd`s value is the last node that's mean is `[7]` after the loop.

I guessed that: the `odd` node should start from node 7 not from node 1 cuz in the loop removed all other nodes `[1,3,5]`

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are saying. When you say *"the result will be `[1,3,5,7,...]`"*, that is only partially true, because that is not what `odd` is referring to, but `head`. That is an important difference. `odd` will still point to 7, but it is not `odd` that we return. We return `head`. I think the representations I added in my answer clearly indicate the difference between `odd` and `head`

Comment: Look at the third diagram I presented, and look where `odd` is pointing (7): that is somewhere in the middle of the chain. If we were to return `odd`, then the caller would only "see" [7, 2, 4, 6]. But we return `head`.